# how to open multiple pages ONMOUSEOVER

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, openpop

I want my link or image to open multiple pages when mouse is over it without clicking, i mean using ONMOUSEOVER or javascript. is it possible? if yes how? thanks .

Comment: what have you tried?  Really just need a simple function and some data that says what you want to open.  Then open it on mouseover

Comment: I tried <a class="asd" href="http://www.w3.org/" onmouseover="window.open (this.href, 'child')">W3C</a> in html but it opens just one page.

Comment: Call `window.open()` twice, and it will open 2 windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately it is possible. Don't do that.

Comment: can you say how to do that? I am not using it online or for opening any ad. just learning.

Answer (score 0):

To open multiple URLs, you will need to move them to a JavaScript function:

## HTML

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="openItAll();">W3C</a>
```

## JavaScript

```
function openItAll()
{
  window.open ('http://w3.org','child');
  window.open ('http://google.com','child');
  return false;
}
```